Calculation K- and L- absorption edge of Yttrium, why do the values deviate significantly from the literature values? Moseley's law
I want to calculate the K- and L- absorption edge of Yttrium
I am using Moseley's law:
$$E=(Z - \sigma)^2 \cdot 13.6\text{eV} \left( \frac{1}{n_i^2} - \frac{1}{n_f^2} \right)$$
So, in this case:
$$E=(39- \sigma)^2 \cdot 13.6\text{eV} \left( \frac{1}{n_i^2} - \frac{1}{n_f^2} \right)$$
For the K-edge, $n_f=2$ and $n_i=1$, because for this transition, the photon energy is resonantly absorbed. Substituting these values, I get:
$$E_K=(39 - 1)^2 \cdot 13.6\text{eV} \left( \frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2^2} \right)=14,728 \text{keV}$$
For the L-edge, I would set the final principal quantum number $n_f=3$and the initial principal quantum number $n_i=2$. Additionally, $\sigma_L= 7.4$.
$$E_L=(39 - 7.4)^2 \cdot 13.6\text{eV} \left( \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{3^2} \right)=1,886 \text{keV}$$
Is this calculated correctly? The value for the K-edge deviates significantly from the literature value, so I think I am doing something wrong. I do not yet fully understand how to determine the absorption edges.
Element 39: Y       Atomic mass:   88.9059
Edge          keV
K        17.0384
L-I       2.3725
L-II      2.1555
L-III     2.0800

The absorption level goes to the nearesz unoccupied level, not from 1 to 2 or 2 to 3
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_absorption_spectroscopy
